# How can I delete a commit to git

Tags: git, github, git-commit

There are a few commits on a remote branch that i would like to get rid of. For example if the history looks like:

```
A->B->C->D
```

I would like to delete C and D to give me:

```
A->B
```

where B is now HEAD?

Comment: See the attached question; except you want `HEAD~2` (to delete the last 2 commits).

Comment: Use `git reset` to delete commits. [This guide](http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html) explains what it does.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am going to lay out all the different ways to delete commits for you and when you should use them. 
**Before you do any of these I highly recommend you copy your branch to another branch just to be safe.**

Do this by doing `git checkout -b copy_branch` and then switch back to your original branch by doing `git checkout the_branch_i_want_to_delete_from_again`

If you have already pushed, as in your case, you can skip to #3, but if you haven't pushed you can look at 1 and 2.

**1) I have not pushed yet or am working alone and the commit(s) I want to remove are the most recent commits:**

If i have:
A---B---C---D

and I want to delete C and D.

Then do `git reset --hard sha_of_B`

which results in:
A---B

If you have already pushed, as in your case, you could still do it this way then do a `git push --force origin the_branch`, but this is not recommended as you could mess other people up working on this project. You should follow #3 instead.

**2) I have not pushed yet or am working alone  and the commits(s) I want to remove are in the middle of my branch:**

If i have:
A---B---C---D

and I want do delete C.

```
git rebase -i sha_of_B_the_commit_before_the_one_i_want_to_delete
```

which opens up the extremely useful interactive rebase screen:

```
pick sha_of_C C
pick sha_of_D D
```

As git prompts you **"# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST."**  that is what we are going to do.

I delete the line `pick sha_of_C C`, which leaves me with:

```
pick sha_of_D D
```

I save it in vi with :wq, which results in:

A---B---D

If you have already pushed, as in your case, you could still do it this way then do a `git push --force origin the_branch`, but this is not recommended as you could mess other people up working on this project. You should follow #3 instead.

**3) I have already pushed and I am working with other people:**

If I have:
A---B---C---D
and I want to delete C and D.

Then do

```
git revert sha_of_D
```

Note that you may have to resolve conflicts here and then commit.
Then do

```
git revert sha_of_C
```

Note that you may have to resolve conflicts here and then commit.

This results in:

A---B---C---D---Reverted_D---Reverted_C

This is safe to push as you are really just adding a commit that reverses all of C's and D's changes, essentially deleting it.

**You should generally avoid doing a `git push --force`  at all costs unless absolutely necessary. But If you are about to do a push force, use protection, you should definitely make a copy of your branch before doing so. It is generally a good rule to just stick to #3 if you have already pushed at all.**

Hopefully this is helpful.

Dan

Answer (score 2):

To delete last commit

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
```

To delete the latest 2 commits

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

You can download the branch locally. Then delete the commits and perform a push --force

```
$ git pull origin
$ git checkout origin/<branchname>
$ git checkout -b <branchname>
$ git reset --hard HEAD~2
$ git push origin <branchname> --force
```